# How I add log 4 net for MAUI application vs 2022 v 17.2

Tags: log4net, maui

How I add log 4 net for MAUI application vs 2022 v 17.2 ?
In Worker service I used this code:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
           .UseWindowsService()
           .UseSystemd()
           .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
           {
               services.AddHostedService<Worker>();

           })
        .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Program));
            var pathToConfig = Path.Combine(
                      hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath
                     , "Logger/log4net.config");
            var logManager = new AppLogManager(pathToConfig, assembly);

            logging.AddLog4Net(new Log4NetProviderOptions
            {
                ExternalConfigurationSetup = true
            });
        });
```

Comment: Any suggestion how to use log4net in MAUI

Comment: I haven't used log4net, but the `log4net nuget` says it supports ".NET Standard 1.3". That nuget should work in any .net 6 project, AFAIK. Not sure how you configure it.

Comment: Can you give sample code ?

Comment: How to configure it.